# Using AppleScript to click on the correct button

Tags: mac, applications, click

I would like to code a simple program to click on one of 3 different buttons: Red, Yellow, or Blue, depending on what the prompt shows. If the prompt says "Red" it has to click on red etc.

[image]

Here is says Yellow so the program has to click on the yellow button in the middle (even though the text is red).

Can anyone help me to code this?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I don't know how to code the script so that it can read the word. I know how to make it click on certain coordinates but I have no idea how to make it read "Yellow" for example.. I don't know if anyone can help me, I'm not advanced enough to make it

Comment: What have you tried so far? What AppleScript coding problem(s) are you having? Please [edit] in more information to help supply a solution.

Comment: You should edit your questions to include any code you've tried so we can help you improve your understanding. Here's the [best source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html) of how to use AppleScript. You might want to consider using [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/).